# Compiling Gearman extension for PHP on OS-X Snow Leopard with Zend Server Community Edition

Tags: php, macos, gearman

I was wondering if anyone else has figured out how to solve this problem.  Whether I install the extension via PECL or compile it by hand, I get the same error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gearman.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gearman.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gearman.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem and I can only bang my head into my desk so many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting help from the people I follow in Twitter, Ralph Schindler from Zend talked me through how to do this via Skype chat:

http://ralphschindler.com/2010/05/12/compiling-gearman-or-anything-for-zend-server-ce-on-snow-leopard